# Postgres division of two subquery sums using WHERE from another subquery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We store volunteer hours in a database for every user, i'm trying to figure out how to structure a Postgres SQL query to find the percentage of total hours a specific user has spent at a location vs the total number of hours at that location (by any user)

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
  id INT,
  userId INT,
  volunteerHours DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
  location INT
);

INSERT INTO entries (id, userId, volunteerHours, location) VALUES (1, 1, 3.0, 2);
INSERT INTO entries (id, userId, volunteerHours, location) VALUES (2, 1, 3.0, 1);
INSERT INTO entries (id, userId, volunteerHours, location) VALUES (3, 1, 3.0, 1);
INSERT INTO entries (id, userId, volunteerHours, location) VALUES (4, 2, 3.0, 1);
INSERT INTO entries (id, userId, volunteerHours, location) VALUES (5, 2, 3.0, 1);
```

*There could be hundreds of these entries in the db, these are shown just for examples*

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT
(SELECT location from entries ORDER BY id DESC FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) as lastEntryLocation,
(SELECT SUM(volunteerHours) from entries WHERE userId = 2 AND location = lastEntryLocation) as userHours,
(SELECT SUM(volunteerHours) from entries AND location = lastEntryLocation) as totalHours,
(SELECT userHours / totalHours) as userContributionPercentage
```

I'm still learning how to write custom SQL queries, hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction of how I should be structuring this query correctly, to return in this situation **0.50**

Thought process from sudo query:

1. Pull the latest entry in the db to determine the last location ID value inserted
2. Use last location value ID to then query the `SUM` of all `userId 2`'s hours
3. Use last location value ID to query the `SUM` of all users hours
4. Divide `userId 2`'s total hours by the total hours at that specific location

I would like to try and do all of this in a SQL query if possible (I could break it out into separate SQL query calls and programmatically do the math, but I would prefer to learn how to do this through one SQL query call if at all possible.

Created a db fiddle as well for this:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/4

If you could also explain why you chose a specific method used to create the query for this, that would greatly help me to understand the reasoning behind it and know where to look further to learn more myself.  Thank you!

EDIT: Looking for a way to not have to do the query twice for the latest location (as it feels like the wrong way to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) with sums for each row's partition/group:

```sql
select distinct on (e.userId) 
    sum(e.volunteerHours) over (partition by userId,location,id)
      / sum(e.volunteerHours) over (partition by userId,location) 
            as percentage_volunteered_here
from entries e
where userId=1
order by userId, id desc;
```

[`Distinct on (a) a,c...order by a,b`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) lets you take the first row for each `a`, according to your desired order/priority - in your case, the latest location.

An equivalent using subqueries:

```sql
select distinct on (userId) 
  (  select sum(volunteerHours) 
     from entries e2 
     where e1.userId=e2.userId 
     and e1.location=e2.location
     and e1.id=e2.id) --hours_during_this_visit_at_location
  /( select sum(volunteerHours) --total_hours_at_this_location
     from entries e2 
     where e1.userId=e2.userId
     and e1.location=e2.location) as percentage_volunteered_here
from entries e1
where userId=1
order by userId, id desc;
```

You might enjoy how your line of thought can be mapped directly, step for step, into a few [`WITH` common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```sql
with 
 last_location_per_user as (
    select distinct on (userId) 
            userId, 
            location,
            volunteerHours
    from entries
    where userId=1
    order by userId, id desc
 ),
total_hours_at_last_location_per_user as (
    select  e.userId, 
            sum(e.volunteerHours)
    from    entries e
        inner join last_location_per_user l
            using (userId,location)
    group by userId
)
select  l.volunteerHours/t.sum as percentage_volunteered_here
from    last_location_per_user l,
        total_hours_at_last_location_per_user t
where   t.userId=l.userId;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/13)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Unfortunately when testing these it seems they all return `1` instead of `0.5` but I will research some of these methods and see if i can find where the issue is at

Comment: @sMyles If you copied these queries and used them on data similar to what's in your [new test on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/4) then `1` is the correct result for `userId=2`. [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/7) you can see they all return `0.5` for `userId=2` when ran against the test data in your question. At the end of my answer there's also a demo that targets `userId=1` while running against the new test data, where the correct result is 0.6666.

Comment: Ah you're right, i'm sorry I forgot the last example insert on here (that was in the fiddle).  The idea is that the result should be 0.5 (or 50%) of total hours for that location, i accidentally removed the entry that was for another location, let me test these out thanks for quick reply!

Comment: So if there's only two entries it returns 1 (instead of 0.5) [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/8) .. if I add hours for user 2 and hours for user 1 (at different location), those seem to return 1 still [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/9)

Comment: **1.** You gave 1 entry per user, while still filtering for only one userId. Clearly, if the user was at only 1 location, they spent 100% of their volunteering time in that location, so `1` is correct. **2.** You're adding hours for user 2, but all for the same location, so this user still spends 100% of the time in that location.

Comment: @sMyles Consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/12) test.

Comment: @sMyles after re-reading your question I think I see the misunderstanding. You're after time last spent in the location by total time at that location, not by total time volunteered anywhere.

Comment: Yes sorry if i wasn't 100% clear about that (total hours of user at a specific location / total hours of all users at a specific location).  With the "location" to do this calculation being the last (highest number) in the db

Comment: @sMyles No problem, I've updated the answer and the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dfFZTa2yN3jpSMVLcFXWc/13) link at the end.

Comment: Awesome this is perfect! Thank you so much for your help and explanation, going through this with you I now can work backwards on the original query to understand how all this works, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write a query
but this is not the only(best) way

```sql
SELECT
  ( SELECT
      ( SELECT  SUM(volunteerHours) 
        from    entries 
        WHERE   userId = 2 
        AND     location = (
            SELECT  location 
            from    entries 
            ORDER BY id 
            DESC FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY))
        / 
      ( SELECT  SUM(volunteerHours) 
        from    entries 
        Where   location = (
            SELECT  location 
            from    entries 
            ORDER BY id DESC 
            FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY))
    ) as userContributionPercentage
```

Comment: Doesn't this end up resulting in two queries for the location ID though?  Is there some way to reuse the original query to only have to query once for the location ID?

Comment: That was my main concern, I was able to do it the way you suggested before I posted the question, but it felt like the wrong thing to do when the same value is reused